# Basic laravel route password protection without setting up database?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, basic-authentication

I'm looking for a dead simple password protection solution (username and password stored as key-value pair in array) to a domain (example.com/demo). I know this is bad practice in production but this is just a quick demo to someone. The code I have currently is pretty trivial stuff:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'demo', 'before' => 'auth.basic'], function() {...});
```

Would I have to create my own filter? How would I set it so the filter only works in production?

Comment: Add the username & password in the users table of DB. otherwise create your own filter at filters.php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is as simple as it gets:

```
Route::filter('auth.verybasic', function()
{
    if(Request::getUser() != 'foo' || Request::getPassword() != 'bar'){
        $headers = array('WWW-Authenticate' => 'Basic');
        return Response::make('Invalid credentials.', 401, $headers);
    }
});
```

Regarding the environment restriction, just check with `App::environment()`:

```
Route::filter('auth.verybasic', function()
{
    if(App::environment() != 'production') return;
    // check login (same as above)
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason why it doesn't ask for credentials after I close the browser session?

Comment: Actually it should. Unless the browser has stored it or you haven't *really* closed everything. For testing you could try your browsers "private mode"...

Comment: Does't work in Laravel 8