# How to create custom basic auth or use two middleware in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.2.45 and I have the following routes

```
Route::group([
    'namespace' => 'Api',
    'prefix' => "api",
    'middleware' => 'service'
], function() {

    Route::get('student/{msisdn}/status', 'StudentController@status');

});
```

my middleware is `service` so here is my `config/service.php`

```
<?php 

return [
    'password' => //password here,
    'ip' => //my server ip here,
    'url' => [
        'check_status' => 'http://%s/student/api/checkUser?password=%s&msisdn=%s',

    ]
];
```

This code works fine according to my requirements, but what i want now is to apply basic authentication without database. I just want a hardcorded username and password (its my requirements, otherwise i would use db).

As my middleware is `service` and how will i apply another middleware `basic.auth` on it, is it possible to use two middleware ? or combine both service and basic.auth middle ware and create new middleware? any suggestion, tutorial or example code on how can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add any number of middleware to a route or group of routes.

```
Route::group([
    'namespace' => 'Api',
    'prefix' => "api",
    'middleware' => ['service', 'auth.basic']
], function() {
    Route::get('student/{msisdn}/status', 'StudentController@status');
});
```

As for authentication without a database, you can create a custom middleware and hardcode the login information there. Apply this middleware to all the routes to enforce the auth.

This should get you started. Though you need to convert the filter to a middleware, the code here is pretty straightforward.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28322507/5892849