# Laravel5 auth.basic not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm having a "spotlight" page that should pass an authorization but even after i implemented these it's just going to that page directly

These are the codes in `web.php`

```
Route::get('spotlight', array(
'before' => 'auth.basic',
function()
{
    return view('spotlight');
}));
```

There were similar questions i tried but didn't find a solution. Anything missing here.
Browser based authentication not prompting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321890/basic-laravel-route-password-protection-without-setting-up-database

see this i think this will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using laravel 5.4 you can attach middleware using `middleware()` function

```
Route::get('spotlight', function () {
    return view('spotlight');
})->middleware('auth.basic');
```